# Git: parent commit is younger than descendant?

Tags: git

I was browsing http://arago-project.org/git/projects/linux-omap3.git repo and came across a strange date-thing, which basically says that parent commit is a year younger than its child.

How is this possible?

```
user@ubuntu1004:/f/linux-omap3$ git log -2 --parents  4b8db3b
commit 4b8db3b368f5601717e3ffee0051628ba33172d3 3c0eee3fe6a3a1c745379547c7e7c904aa64f6d5
Author: Kevin Hilman <khilman@deeprootsystems.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 20 11:19:52 2010 -0700

    OMAP: bus-level PM: enable use of runtime PM API for suspend/resume

    [...skipped...]

    Cc: Rajendra Nayak <rnayak@ti.com>
    Signed-off-by: Kevin Hilman <khilman@deeprootsystems.com>

commit 3c0eee3fe6a3a1c745379547c7e7c904aa64f6d5 65f42886e24be2197b1263f138eabf40c6774d00
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Tue Jan 4 16:50:19 2011 -0800

    Linux 2.6.37
```

Comment: Committers can put in any timestamp they want, no? And if someone runs a system with the clock set wrong, that would happen.

Comment: What happens to timestamps of "rebased" commits? Do they keep the original date? Then this could also happen.

Comment: @Thilo I believe they keep the original timestamp.

Comment: There are also two separate dates stored on each commit - the author date and the committer date. These two can differ for many different reasons - rebase, cherry-pick, format-patch/am cycles, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

- you put any timestamp you want on a commit: "[git commit - setting timestamps into the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367262/git-commit-setting-timestamps-into-the-future)"
- you can amend the timestamp of a commit: "[How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git)"
- You are dealing with two dates: `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITER_DATE`: See [working with date in  Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps).

What you see could be the result of a:

- rebase, since `git rebase` does actually not change authors' timestamps by default: see "[git rebase without changing commit timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps)".
- [cherry-picking](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) (as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934044/git-parent-commit-is-younger-than-descendant/12951228#comment17556377_12951228) by [Michael Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221955/michael-anderson)) since it also preserves `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`

Comment: Another way this often happens is cherry-picks, which also preserves timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is way more technically insightful, but I'll just add how this actually happened to me. I was debugging an issue that was affected by the local computer date, and was actively changing my system clock to track down the bug.  After fixing it I committed everything to git unaware that my system clock was still set 2 months in the future, thereby screwing up my git history since I only noticed a few days later when commits showed up out of order in Github (d'oh!).  This is supposedly [fixable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357708/what-is-the-safest-way-to-correct-the-date-of-a-future-dated-commit-in-git-and), though I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Yes, `filter-branch` is the solution in that case.